# Solar panels connected in parallel by opposite polarity

Tags: solar-cell

I have 2 3V solar panels that I want to connect by opposite polarity.

Panel1 +ve terminal will connect to Panel2 -ve terminal.
Panel1 -ve terminal will connect to Panel2 +ve terminal.

Load is connected across these panels. I understand effective voltage will be (v1 - v2) (or (v2 - v1) depending to how measurement is taken).

This works as expected but my question is: is it safe to do? Will there be any damage to the panel that is of lesser voltage?

Comment: Please draw a schematic. It sounds like you have just short circuited two panels.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Finbar - I am trying to build a sensor. Voltage difference is proportional to panel outputs which are mounted in certain way in my application. My first thought was connect them the series but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Connect the negative terminals together and measure the voltage difference between the positive terminals.

Comment: I did that. It is not as expected. When both panels are in sunlight, voltage is close to 0 which is expected.  When I cover 1 panel, voltage barely rises to 300mv.

Comment: I want to do something similar. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wL9PcGu_xrA&ab_channel=QuintBUILDs (around 4:10 in video)

Comment: You probably need to put a bit of load on each panel to get its voltage to vary more according to light level

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Let me try that.